# Unable to setup grafana template with mysql

Tags: mysql, grafana

I'm trying to create a template variable in grafana, but I'm getting this error:

```
Templating
Template variables could not be initialized: a.metricFindQuery is not a function
```

This is my query:

```
select distinct marketplace_name from campaign_machine.marketplace_out_products_history;
```

I'm using MySQL as data source.

How can I fix this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha version of the MySQL plugin does not support Template Variables. Try the 4.5 beta of Grafana which includes a more full-featured data source plugin for MySQL:

https://grafana.com/grafana/download/4.5.0-beta1

Support for template variables was added in this commit:

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/8855#issuecomment-321541864

Docs on how to use template variables with MySQL:

http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/mysql/#templating